# I wanted to know why the tables from hive db which I imported from sqlserver using sqoop is disappearing

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

So I'm trying to import-all-tables into hive db, ie, *user/hive/warehouse/...* on hdfs, using the below command:

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<servername>;database=<dbname>" \
--username "<username>" \
--password "<password>" \
--warehouse-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/" \
--hive-import \
-m 1
```

In the testdatabase I have 3 tables, when mapreduce runs, the output is success, 
ie, the mapreduce job is 100% complete but the file is not found on hive db.

Comment: Which path in HDFS did you check?

Comment: The file from sqlserver was suppose to go into "/user/hive/warehouse" directory, but now only one table is seen in the directory and I am getting this pop up :  "Path does not exist on HDFS or WebHDFS is disabled. Please check your path or enable WebHDFS"

Answer (score 0):

It’s basically getting overwritten by the last table, try removing the forward slash at the end of the directory path. For the tests I would suggest not to use the warehouse directory, use something like ‘/tmp/sqoop/allTables’

Comment: I am not sure if it;s getting overwritten, because, now I am trying to create a Hive table, which says OK> after creation and gives the table name in "Show tables;" command but when I manually check in the warehouse the table is not present. this is how I created the table : 
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS XYZ(Code 
    VARCHAR(25), Address(25), Date DATE, Type VARCHAR(25)) ROW 
    FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS 
    TEXTFILE location '/user/hive/warehouse/xyz';

Answer (score 0):

There is a another way
1. Create a hive database pointing to a location says "targetLocation"
2. Create hcatalog table in your sqoop import using previously created database.
3. Use target-directory import options to point that targetLocation.

Answer (score 0):

> you doesn't need need to define  warehouse directory.just define hive database it will automatically find out working directory.

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx;databaseName=master" --username xxxxxx --password xxxxxxx --hive-import --create-hive-table  --hive-database test -m 1
```

> it will just run like rocket.

hope it work for you....